# Fatal error: cron install error

Tags: magento2.2, cron, crontab

i'm getting this cron install error, how can i fix it?thankyou!!

php bin/magento cron:install --force

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Crontab/CrontabManager.php:202

Comment: Did you try o run setup:di:compile before?

Comment: Please use `php bin/magento cron:run`      command to ensure cron is running in Magento after that you can set the cron

Comment: yes,but can not, Fatal error @PurushotamSharma

Comment: maybe no, so i need run setup:di:compile?thank you @Vulpea

Comment: Hi @niceonelee, you've got any solution for this? I have the same error

Answer (score 1):

The exception handler for the actual error is failing. It expects a previous exception, but there is none.

The actual error is the `exec` method being disabled by php.ini `disabled_functions`.

```php
        $disabled = explode(',', str_replace(' ', ',', ini_get('disable_functions')));
        if (in_array('exec', $disabled)) {
            throw new Exception\LocalizedException(new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('The exec function is disabled.'));
        }
```

Source: [GitHub.com](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Shell.php#L53)